# Android tumbles custom TextViews onResume

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, onresume

### Background

I have an App with multiple custom TextViews in it.
These four Custom TextViews are all set up like this:

```
public class TextView_Light extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public TextView_Light(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public TextView_Light(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TextView_Light(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);
}}
```

I do have `TextView_Bold`, `TextView_Light`, `TextView_Regular` and `TextView_Thin`. Each of them uses another font which is saved in `assets/fonts`

I use the TextViews like that:

```
<de.mayr.wap.app.helper.TextView_Light
            android:id="@+id/textView_Light7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/overviewViaBarcode"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

When the App is started and a view shows up for the first time everything looks great, like that:
[image: Fine looking view]

---

### The Problem

In this view the user klicks on one of the tablerows, an `Dialog` appears where the user types in some data. On save the `onResume` method of the view is called, which calls an Webservice etc. like that:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    callSerNrWS();
}


public void callSerNrWS() {
    if (CheckNetwork.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
        final AsyncResponseFortschritt<ResponseObject<PruefauftraegeVO>> response = new AsyncResponseFortschritt<ResponseObject<PruefauftraegeVO>>() {
            @Override
            public void processFinishSerNr(ResponseObject<PruefauftraegeVO> output) {
                anw = createPruefAnwArraylist();
                seriennummerVO = findDataToSerNr();
                adapt = new PruefAnwAdapter(getContext(), anw, seriennummerVO);
                pruefListView.setAdapter(adapt);
                setVisibilityLoadAnimation(View.GONE);
                if (output.getException() != null && !output.getException().isEmpty())
                    AlertCreator.makeFailAlert(R.string.titelKeinFortschritt, R.string.textKeinFortschritt,getContext());
            }
            @Override
            public void processStartSerNr() {
                setVisibilityLoadAnimation(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
        AsyncCallSerNrWS ws = new AsyncCallSerNrWS(response, pruefauftraegeVO);
        ws.execute();
    }
}
```

And after that, theres in 90% of cases one or more `TextView` which changed its **looking** from eg. `TextView_Light` to `TextView_Thin`. Like in the following picture: The appearence of the 'Anzugstrom [A]' in the third row now looks like a `TextView_Thin` and the '9/48' in the fifth row looks like a `TextView_Light`
[image: Bad looking view]

---

### What I know

- This doesnt happen when the view is shown for the first time
- There isn't any system behind it. It's totally random.
- It happens in activitys and fragments
- It happens in every view i have whatever the TextView contains 'hard-coded' text or text that comes from an Webservice
- Its not just in lists, also in 'normal' views

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this happens when not using ListView or RecyclerView? This sounds like the classic case of view recycling doing something you didn't expect. Unrelated: have you tried using the built-in light/thin/bold typefaces instead of creating your own custom TextView class?

Comment: In another view theres a ConstraintLayout containing a TableRow containing a ConstraintLayout containing multiple TextViews. And these are also becoming tumbled up... Yes. I could use the build in TextViews... I had to change the 100 - 150 TextView in my app. That yould be ok if its necessary. But: I would really like to understand why this is happening... There must be a reason somewhere...